# Need sql statement review for vb.net windows forms express desktop 2013

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

I have been working at this sql statement for about 2 hours now and I can not get it to work for the life of me. I am pretty sure that all the columns names and table names are correct but im getting a syntax error at the third row on the first period. Can you guys double check my statement to make sure im not missing anything. Also, I ran this code on my sql server and it worked so im wondering why it wont work in vb.net. Maybe vb.net doesn't support something here?

```
 Try

                Dim A As String = CBShear.Text
                Dim B As String = CBName.Text
                Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                    conn1.Open()
                    Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Production.dbo.tblFabWipLog (FabWipId, Shear, CheckedIn, NameIn, CartType)" _
                        & "SELECT TOP 1 FabWipID, cast('" & A & "' as varchar), Cast(getdate() as smalldatetime), cast('" & B & "' as varchar), Cast('Mother' as varchar)" _
                       & "FROM production.dbo.tblFabWipID WHERE FabWipID NOT IN (Select tblFabWipID.FabWipID" _
 & "FROM Production.dbo.tblFabWipID LEFT JOIN production.dbo.tblFabWipLog ON tblFabWIPID.FabWipID = tblFabWipLog.FabWipID WHERE Active = 1 AND CheckedOut IS NULL" _
  & "AND NOT CheckedIn IS NULL) AND LocID LIKE 'M%' ORDER BY LocID ASC)", conn1)

                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
                        Dim rs As New SqlDataAdapter
                        rs.SelectCommand = comm1
                        rs.Fill(dt)
                        DGVCheck.DataSource = dt

                    End Using
                End Using


            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

Comment: update, its the 4th row of the sql statement.

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: I changed it over to .addwithvalue parameters to make it safer. I also have integrated security in my standard sql connection and I am also only allowing users to input data through a combo box that has a drop down list that can be selected from. The users can not enter their own text. Also, i doubt this will ever be hacked on the purpose that there is no reason too.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I was only using the ".text" applications for testing. Please see comment above.

Comment: [AddWithValue() isn't that great, either.](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your string-building for your SQL statement, you have no spaces where you need them.  They way its written, here's what your select statement looks like when it's compiled, and probably explains why it doesn't work.

`INSERT INTO Production.dbo.tblFabWipLog (FabWipId, Shear, CheckedIn, NameIn, CartType)SELECT TOP 1 FabWipID, cast('[somevalue]' as varchar), Cast(getdate() as smalldatetime), cast('[somevalue]' as varchar), Cast('Mother' as varchar)FROM production.dbo.tblFabWipID WHERE FabWipID NOT IN (Select tblFabWipID.FabWipIDFROM Production.dbo.tblFabWipID LEFT JOIN production.dbo.tblFabWipLog ON tblFabWIPID.FabWipID = tblFabWipLog.FabWipID WHERE Active = 1 AND CheckedOut IS NULLAND NOT CheckedIn IS NULL) AND LocID LIKE 'M%' ORDER BY LocID ASC)`

The best way to handle these types of query-building routines to use a variable to build the string and then put a break point so you can cut/copy/paste into Sql Mgt Studio to ensure the query works as your SQL statement is generated at run-time.

Comment: It looks like i may have one or two more syntax errors but that appears to be the main problem. thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have spaces at the end of each line you are concatenating.

```
Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Production.dbo.tblFabWipLog (FabWipId, Shear, CheckedIn, NameIn, CartType) " _
& "SELECT TOP 1 FabWipID, cast('" & A & "' as varchar), Cast(getdate() as smalldatetime), cast('" & B & "' as varchar), Cast('Mother' as varchar) " _
& "FROM production.dbo.tblFabWipID WHERE FabWipID NOT IN (Select tblFabWipID.FabWipID " _
& "FROM Production.dbo.tblFabWipID LEFT JOIN production.dbo.tblFabWipLog ON tblFabWIPID.FabWipID = tblFabWipLog.FabWipID WHERE Active = 1 AND CheckedOut IS NULL " _
& "AND NOT CheckedIn IS NULL) AND LocID LIKE 'M%' ORDER BY LocID ASC)", conn1)
```

Comment: This has fixed the main problem +1. Thanks!